# How do I make it so that a wooden axe can break only oak logs on minecraft pocket-edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I play MCPE, and I’ve been trying to figure out how to give someone a wooden axe that can only break oak logs. I’ve been using this:

```
/give @p wooden_axe 1 0 {can_destroy:”blocks”:[“minecraft:log”]}
```

but it hasn’t been working, what command should I use?

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy your command directly exactly as entered, because those quotation marks are not the correct ones for commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374598/how-can-i-use-canplaceon-and-candestroy-in-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type of Log. If you want it to only break Oak Logs the command would be /give @p wooden_axe 1 0 {can_destroy:”blocks”:[“minecraft:oak_log”}